# What to do if you recognise Assignment Questions on this site?

Tags: support, homework

I have observed that one specific user on this site has been posting questions that are identical to the questions that are in my University Assignment.

Is there a way to report such posts that are a breech of academic integrity?

Comment: This has been discussed a couple of times. IIRC the discussion converged to: 1) While this is lamentable, we have no way of enforcing any rules about potential breeches of honor code, 2) The advice is that you bring any honor code violations to the attention of the teacher who assigned the problem handled on our site.

Comment: You see, many teachers encourage their students to use the site as a learning aid (to an extent I do so myself, but very few do - possibly due to language). Also, in many places homework performance plays a minimal (or non-existent) role in the grade of student, so some other students asking the exact same question will not be in violation of any academic code.

Comment: This particular breech is in an actual assignment, of which marks and grading is allocated as a percentage of the course.

Comment: Probably you should be able to find some similar older discussions if you search a bit. Here are a few I was able to find:
[One of my students may be getting math.SE to do their homework](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/one-of-my-students-may-be-getting-math-se-to-do-their-homework),
[Student posting assignment questions - what action to take?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21539/student-posting-assignment-questions-what-action-to-take),
[Posting exam questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9021/posting-exam-questions).

Comment: Thanks for the links, Martin. Hugh, from those discussions you see that the sentiment of the user base is on your side. Your best approach is probably to post comments under the offending posts. Flagging them will summon a moderator to the scene, but you still need to deal with the matter at your University. For example, we are not allowed to disclose any information identifying the poster (presumably they use an alias when posting) - not that we have access to useful amounts of such information ourselves.

Comment: And I may have been taken aback a bit by your choice of phrase *to report* - sorry about that. But, report, to whom? If to other users so that they know not to post answers, then commenting is your remedy (but some of the answerers are too eager to answer not to notice such a comment). If to moderators of the site, then flagging the violating posts is your best option, but moderators may arrive at the scene too late to prevent answers from appearing.

Comment: When I recognize questions that I assigned to my students, I answer them. The same way I'd answer them in an email, or in office hours. This is just another outlet for students to use.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But these are questions that are in assignments, you wouldn't give the answer then surely? (Assignment as opposed to homework in the sense that an Assignment is marked, graded and has a relatively significant weighting to the course) It just seems a bit dishonest to me. 

Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: When I asked some of my students why they are not using this site, the common answer is that I am going to be the one who answers them anyway, so might as well write an email and get an even faster reply. I believe that assignments are a two-part contract: they are either very easy, and a student should be able to easily solve them; or they are hard, and the teacher should be ever present to give hints and guidance.

Comment: So how about a discussion for those of us who are not taking your pre calc course but instead taking a Moore method proofs course that demands in the syllabus that no help is to be sought from outside texts / internet / or students not in the class, only the professor or your classmates can help. I myself have seen questions posted from my classmates, then preceded to present the proof provided in answers as their own work to the class the next day. @AsafKaragila